# LDAP implementation

Tags: ldap, sssd, aws-directory-services

I want to implementation centralize auth using AWS Simple AD (samba). The client machine is linux based (ubuntu and amazon linux). Ony my ldap, i just creat one user (`cn=test`) under `dc=ldap,dc=test,dc=io`.

I am using sssd as the auth client from my linux machine. And here my `/etc/sssd/sssd.conf` :

```
[sssd]
config_file_version = 2
services = nss, pam
domains = LDAP

[nss]

[pam]

[domain/LDAP]
id_provider = ldap
auth_provider = ldap
ldap_schema = rfc2307
ldap_uri = ldap://ldap.test.io
ldap_default_bind_dn = dc=ldap,dc=test,dc=io
ldap_default_authtok = password01
ldap_default_authtok_type = password
ldap_search_base = dc=ldap,dc=test,dc=io
ldap_user_search_base = dc=ldap,dc=test,dc=io
ldap_group_search_base = odc=ldap,dc=test,dc=io
ldap_user_object_class = inetOrgPerson
ldap_user_gecos = cn
override_shell = /bin/bash
cache_credentials = true
enumerate = true
```

But, it looks like not working from the client, i didn't get the ldap user from my client (i execute this `getent passwd`).

And i got this error:

```
nss_ldap: reconnecting to LDAP server...
nss_ldap: reconnecting to LDAP server (sleeping 1 seconds)...
nss_ldap: could not search LDAP server - Server is unavailable
No passwd entry for user 'test'
```

Here is my reference to configure the sssd client [enter link description here](https://www.ossramblings.com/ubuntu-14.04-sssd-and-openldap-authentication)

### Any suggestion for this case ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error message you are getting is from nss_ldap, not from nss_sss. So I assume in /etc/nsswitch.conf, you configured the ldap module either on its own or before sss. If the user information is to be returned by sssd then use the sss nsswich module.

I would also recommend to not use enumerate=true unless your directory is quite small.

Answer (score 0):

In `/etc/nsswitch.conf` be sure to have:

```
passwd: files sss
shadow: files sss
groups: files sss
```

And of course in the stack of the `/etc/pam.d/system-auth-ac` and `/etc/pam.d/password-auth-ac` you have to use the `pam_sss.so` library.